# How do I create a function to find average above median?

Tags: python

I want to find the average of all scores above and below the median (not including the median), but I have no idea have to go about doing this.

```
import collections

def main():
    names = ["gymnastics_school", "participant_name", "all_around_points_earned"]
    Data = collections.namedtuple("Data", names)
    data = []
    values =[]

    with open('state_meet.txt','r') as f:   
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            items = line.split(',')
            items[2] = float(items[2])
            data.append(Data(*items))        
            values.append(items[2])
    print("summary of data:")



    sorted_data = sorted (values)
    if len(data)%2==0:
        a =sorted_data[len(values)//2]

        b = sorted_data[len(values)//2-1]
        median_val = (a+b)//2
    else:
        median_val = sorted_data[(len(values)-1)//2]

    print("   median score",median_val)   #median
```

Comment: Python has a [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) as part of the standard library!

Comment: You're missing a question.

Comment: What does this code have to do with your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now have [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) as part of the standard library:

```
import statistics

nums = list(range(10))
med = statistics.median(nums)

hi_avg = statistics.mean(i for i in nums if i > med)
lo_avg = statistics.mean(i for i in nums if i < med)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a valid approach for large data. You're iterating through the entire dataset. If say, we're dealing with a 4D MRI image (90 x 90 x 60 x 10) with 4,860,000 iterations for each process? This will take a week to finish!

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri, I don't understand; 4.8 million observations isn't large data. I just ran this with `range(4860000)` no problem. Also, the question doesn't mention scale and the OP is already reading the data into memory and sorting.

Comment: Chris, I didn't make an aggressive comment, merely an opinion? Regarding 4.86m, trust me, it is when it comes to data of float64 in 4D images. Here is the closest example I can come up with: `a = [a**2 for a in np.random.rand(int(4.68e6))]` vs  `np.random.rand(int(4.68e6))**2` . The former takes 1.53 sec and the latter 73.7 ms (over 20 times faster). I didn't mean your solution was invalid. For me as someone who specialises in optimisation, it is not a valid approach. The solution nonetheless remains a valid one. Also, we should always consider the data, because we never know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the build-in function `filter` and `sum`. For example

```
above_med = filter(lambda x: x>median_val,  values)
print(" average of scores above median ", sum(above_med)/len(above_med))
```

## Edited:

As suggested by @ChrisP, you can also use the standard package `statistics` introduced since python 3.4.

Comment: what about the below/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

data_array = np.array(data)

med = np.median(data)

ave_above_med = data_array[data_array > med].mean()
```

so the function would be:

```
import numpy as np

def average_above_med(data):
    data_array = np.array(data)
    med = np.median(data)
    response = data_array[data_array > med].mean()

    return response
```

This is a test of that:

```
test_data = [1, 5, 66, 7, 5]
print(average_above_med(test_data))
```

which displays:

```
36.5
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: what about the below?

Comment: I would personally use `Numpy` because it uses vectorisation (as opposed to iteration implemented in C or Fortran) and is as such considerably faster when dealing with large volumes of data.

Comment: Oh and please not that had written `data` instead of `data_array` in my function. I have now corrected that.